# Проблема с алиас (синоним)

Tags: javascript, alias

Обратите внимание на алиас (синоним) R, которому дал метод wid.document.write, чтобы иметь возможность кратко вызывать его как R(...).

```
<HEAD>
  <SCRIPT>
    wid = window.open('','','width=750,height=100,status=yes');
    wid.document.open(); R = wid.document.write;
    R('<HTML><HEAD><SCRIPT>var t;<\/SCRIPT></HEAD>');
    R('<BODY><H1>Новое окно</H1></BODY></HTML>');
    wid.document.close();
  </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <A HREF="javascript:
  wid.t=window.prompt('Новое состояние:','');
  wid.document.write(wid.t); wid.focus(); void(0);"
  >Изменим значение переменной t в новом окне</A>
</BODY>
```

FireFox работает корректно, а вот дебагер в Chrome ругается на

`R('<HTML><HEAD><SCRIPT>var t;<\/SCRIPT></HEAD>');`

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Переписал script следующим образом

```
<SCRIPT>
    wid = window.open('','','width=750,height=100,status=yes');
    wid.document.open();
    wid.document.write('<HTML><HEAD><SCRIPT>var t;<\/SCRIPT></HEAD>');
    wid.document.write('<BODY><H1>Новое окно</H1></BODY></HTML>');
    wid.document.close();
</SCRIPT>
```

FireFox так же работает корректно. Chrome перестал ругаться. Как правильно задать синоним R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, *write* завязан на контекст в котором вызывается, для сохранения его нужно использовать [*bind*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
var R = wid.document.write.bind(wid.document);
```

Comment: Недавно начал изучать. Спасибо огромное за пояснение.